Managing Prisma schema relationships within a polyrepo project
I am building a NextJS backend application and have opted for a polyrepo approach with each repository being it's own service. Each service has it's own Prisma schema but they all create tables in the same database. I wanted this approach to ensure only the relevant service could interact/manage it's own table. The problem I have comes with defining relationships.
Say I have two services, a users service and a posts service. In the posts services Prisma schema I want a foreign key referencing a users unique ID from the users table, which is created in the users service. However, the models are obviously unaware of each other so I am unable to define this relationship. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Or does anyone have any advice in general on working with Prisma within a polyrepo approach? Am I just better off using a monorepo?
Any advice is appreciated!
